# Hooks without build

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can we use react hooks without npm, but simply by using attaching

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

In an html file? 
I'm able to use react but not react hooks.
I'm at the newest version of react that has hooks.

Comment: I also imported <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> and <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> by the way, so I don't think I have missing imports up there